# Saving a Rails Record with a specific Timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

How to save an event in *Berlin* with its own specific timezone and the next event in *Tijuana* with a different one?

The user is asked to choose a City for the event, as a source for e.g. *+02:00*.

I would like to receive a time code like this:

```
eventstart = "2011-07-22T18:00:00+02:00"
```

How would you go about creating that form?

**UPDATE:**

Realized saving as standard UTC is fine for many reasons. So now I am altering a time string in the view to present a *distance_to_time_in_words* for *eventstart*, depending on the user's local time.

Event in Tijuana, viewing from Berlin time:

```
old_zone = Time.zone
#=> "Berlin"
Time.zone = "Tijuana"
t = Time.zone.parse(eventstart.to_s[0..-7])
#=> 2011-07-22 18:00:00 +08:00
Time.zone = old_zone
#=> "Berlin"
distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now.in_time_zone, t)
#=> "9 hours"
```

cumbersome, but works for now. Improvement ideas welcome!

Answer (score 7):

Add a `time_zone` column to your database and use `time_zone_select` in your form to let user select the `time_zone` for which he is creating event.

And in the model you can convert the datetime to zone specific datetime and store utc in the database. You can use helper something like below

```
def local_time(date)
  Time.use_zone(self.time_zone) do
    Time.zone.at(date.to_i)
  end
end
```

Comment: Just tested this in the model
`def local_time(date)
    Time.use_zone("Paris") do
      Time.zone.at(date.to_i)
    end
  end`
.

From the view
`<%= @event.local_time("2011-07-23 00:00:00 +0200") %>`

results in `1970-01-01 01:33:31 +0100`

Comment: It worked for me unless you are doing wrong somewhere(and we use extensively in our project). You can test first local_time method in Rails console or through unit test. if you try this out in console it should print time in Paris time zone. just copy paste the code in console  `code` def local_time(d); Time.use_zone("Paris") do ; Time.zone.at(d.to_i); end; end;local_time(Time.parse("2011-07-23 00:00:00")) `code`. You cannot pass string to local_time as in your comment above. you should be passing date or datetime object.

Comment: It works, must have been the datetime object i was missing. Thank you

Comment: Sorry to be back, but i just realized, while your solution works in its own regard, i need a different behaviour.  Your solution converts _2011-07-23 01:00:00 +0100_ to _2011-07-22 21:00:00 -0300:    I need the time to remain the same while receiving a new time zone.  So in this example like _2011-07-23 01:00:00 -0300_  Here's similar question, i just came accross: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074238/how-to-get-rails-to-interpret-a-time-as-being-in-a-specific-time-zone